# Why is my code not reading/printing forward, I am using loops to fill up arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


int s = 0;
Console.WriteLine("How many soldiers: ");
s= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] sol = new string [s];
Console.WriteLine("Enter names of "+s +"soldiers");

for (int i = 0; i < sol.Length; i++)
{
    sol[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
 
 Array.Sort(sol);
 Console.WriteLine("Names in order: ");

 for (int i = 0; i < sol.Length; i++)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(sol[i]);
 }
 
Console.WriteLine("it works");
```

I am able to input number of soldiers and also their names but after that I get nothing. Also, if I remove the `console.readline()` from the first for loop, the program just closes. I am new to programming.

What can I try next?

Comment: You're reading two lines in each iteration of the loop. Once into the array and the second is discarded. Is that intentional?

Comment: Debug your code. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, inspecting the state at each step. You will then be able to see exactly where and how the code is not behaving as you expect. If it is behaving as you expect but doesn't produce the result you want then it's your expectations that need to change.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fdebugger%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2022) is a tutorial on how to use the debugger (including setting breakpoints and stepping through the code). Looking at the content of `sol` as you step through the code with the debugger may bring more clarity to what is actually happening when providing soldier names in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Without the extra `Console.Readline()` your code does in fact work. The problem, however, is that it closes so fast that you do not see the result.  You therefore need to put a final `Console.Readline()` in, so that the program pauses, in order to give you the chance to see the results.  Something like this:

```
int s = 0;
Console.WriteLine("How many soldiers: ");
s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] sol = new string[s];

Console.WriteLine($"Enter names of { s } soldiers");


for (int i = 0; i < sol.Length; i++)
{
    sol[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

Array.Sort(sol);
Console.WriteLine("Names in order: ");

for (int i = 0; i < sol.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sol[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine("it works");
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close");
Console.ReadLine();
```